# Get my second horizontal grid splitter working correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, gridsplitter

I am confused with `GridSplitter` objects:

[image: Vertical Splitter]

The above has a vertical splitter:

```
<GridSplitter
    Width="5" 
    Background="LightGray"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="4"
    Grid.Column="0" />
```

It behaves correctly and resizes the columns.

But I was trying to add a horizontal grid splitter:

```
<GridSplitter
    Width="5" 
    Background="Black"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    ResizeDirection="Rows"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0" />
```

But see the black line? That is in the wrong place. It should be *horizontal*, between the two `GroupBox` items:

[image: How it should be]

What is wrong with my markup logic? Interestingly, if I set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` or `Center` then the splitter will not even display, let alone work.

Thank you.

Update:

[image: Resized]

Above is resized control (thanks for your answer). But only the groupbox (in this context) should resize. The content of the groupbox can stay at the top.

Update: Fixed the resizing of controls bu changing the `RowDefinition` height values from `1*` to `auto`.

Comment: Try setting the `VerticalContentAlignment="Top"` if the property exists on the GroupBox or setting the `VerticalAlignment=Top` of the root child element of the GroupBox

Comment: I will leave that for now. Do new question another day. Thanks.

Comment: @Nkosi I solved that issue. My `RowDefinition` heights were all set to `1*`. I changed them to `auto`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For horizontal grid splitter you should set the height and horizontal alignment.

```
<GridSplitter
    Height="5" 
    Background="Black"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    ResizeDirection="Rows"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0" />
```

Comment: Here is an example you can look at. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8

Comment: Thanks! As a side note, I see that the **content** of the `GroupBox`stretches. In this case, I want the `GroupBox to adjust but for the content of the `GroupBox` to stay aligned at the top.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean. post pic. It's most probably and alignment issue either with the group box itself or its children.

Comment: Post another question with this issue. include pics and xaml snippet. will see what I can do.

Comment: I updated this question. But I will have to hold off on a new question. It says I can't ask more than 50 questions in 30 days. So I don't know when I can next ask one! Grrh.